# Save attachment of infopath form to some local drive

Tags: infopath, attachments, network-drive

Can I save InfoPath attachments to some shared network or a drive when I click on save button?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this reasonably easily. But it does require using code behind your form. The following Microsoft article describes the process and has sample code to do it:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2517906